# ACC APIs POST issues, issue position problem

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I'm reading the [ACC API Create Issue Documentation](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/issues-issues-POST/) and saw that only the issue title, status and subtype id are required in the request, but I also want to pass the Issue position in the 3D world, which is the point I clicked on the Viewer, like:

[image: Point with x, y and z coordinates]

But in the docs the only example they give is this, with gpsCoordinates:

[image: Request example in docs]

Is this right? My THREE.js Vector3 must be converted in this 2D latitude and longitude coordinates to send it?

It doesn't fells right to me, but if it is how do I convert it?